# How to load vimeo videos in JW player

Tags: jwplayer, vimeo

I need to embed vimeo video in the JW player. The script I am using is for Loading new content into  the player which can be found here http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/16025/loading-new-content-into-the-player

Can someone help me with the onclick and the setup script for loading videos from vimeo?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think, to embed vimeo videos, you need an additional plugin, a "vimeo media provider" because th JW player has a native support for youtube, but not for vimeo. And finally you need a vimeo pro account for the third party player support (see http://vimeo.com/help/faq/pro)!

Answer (score 0):

If this is still an issue for you, I was able to make this work with a vimeo provider from http://luwes.co/labs/vimeo-provider.  I don't have a Vimeo Pro account, fwiw.  It's $9 and works with the v. 5 Flash player.  If you search for "vimeoprovider.swf", you'll find links to other projects, none of which I've tried, but might be useful.  Good luck!

Comment: BTW, it's worth thinking for a minute about why you want to go the embedding route.  I realized that all I really cared about was counting "play" clicks and checking the amount of time that the video had been viewed, and hese can both be gotten from the APIs for YouTube (https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) and Vimeo (http://developer.vimeo.com/player/js-api). YMMV, but to me this seems a lot cleaner and maybe easier than trying to get one company's product inside another, especially as these products go through different versions.  APIs change, but not that much.